# Jest throwing ReferenceError to default exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

Jest is unable to find functions which are `export default` but IS able to find `export const`. I can go through and redefine how all of my functions are exported/imported, but I feel this is likely just a config issue but have been unable to find any solution on the docs or github issues to solve it.

Does anyone know of some jest config which can be used to resolve this?

**GOOD**
file:

```
export const MyFunction = () => {..
```

spec:

```
import { MyFunction } from "src/MyFunction";
=>   ● Pass
```

**BAD**
file:

```
export default MyFunction = () => {..
```

spec:

```
import MyFunction from "src/MyFunction";
=>   ● Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined
```

My `jest.config.js`:

```
/*
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
 */

module.exports = {
  // All imported modules in your tests should be mocked automatically
  // automock: false,

  // Automatically restore mock state between every test
  restoreMocks: true,

  // Make calling deprecated APIs throw helpful error messages
  errorOnDeprecated: true,

  // An array of directory names to be searched recursively up from the requiring module's location
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src", "test/unit"],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: "node",

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: ["**/test/**/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],

  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)",
  ],

  transform: {
    "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
  },

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],

  reporters: ["default", "jest-junit"],

  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ["lcov", "text-summary"],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "src/img/",
    "src/styles/",
    "test/factories/",
    "test/fixtures/",
  ],

  // Whether to use watchman for file crawling
  watchman: true,

  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"],
  preset: "jest-expo",
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
    THEME: true,
    SEGMENT_KEY_STORE_INFO: true,
    INITIAL_STATE: true,
    EMPTY_MESSAGE: true,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys stupid one here, but the solution is to change the default export to:
`MyFunction.js`:

```
export default () => {..
```

Ie drop the name in the export default function declaration. Hope this helps someone having this issue.

Comment: Or simply declare the function first with `const MyFunction = () => {` and _then_ export it as `export default MyFunction;`, after its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

export default MyFunction = () => {..
Change this to
export default const MyFunction = () => {..

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that will render a `SyntaxError` as the export options are either `default `or `const`